# How to retrieve the selected item in a treeview

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to retrieve the header of the selected item in a treeview.

My code : 
XAML:

```
 <TreeView x:Name="TreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,22,0,10" Width="223" SelectedItemChanged="item" >
        <TreeViewItem x:Name="Accueil" Header="Accueil" RenderTransformOrigin="0.502,-1.125"/>
        <TreeViewItem x:Name="Comptes" Header="Comptes" IsExpanded="True"/>
    </TreeView>
```

C#:

```
private void item(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        string compteselectionne = Convert.ToString(TreeView.SelectedItem);
        if (compteselectionne=="Comptes")
        {
            ListeComptes.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        ListeComptes.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

This code shows me things like System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem Header: Comptes Items.Count: 1

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2):

`string compteselectionne = ((TreeViewItem)TreeView.SelectedItem).Header;`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MVVM approach *properly* you should be binding on `IsSelected` in `TwoWay` (or `OneWayToSource`) mode of `TreeViewItem` and looking for this property to be true on your ViewModels and everything else should be in there.

Example how I'd do it:

XAML (Where my ViewModel has a property on it called `IsSelected` & `HeaderText` for setting header):

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionOfItems}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding HeaderText}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

and in code I can easily find out the current selection by doing:

```
//null result of the following means there's no selection
var selectedItem = MyCollectionOfItems.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsSelected)
```

Comment: On a side note, the same technique also allows you to pull multiple selections if view supports that by changing `SingleOrDefault` to a `Where` (or even `FirstOrDefault` if that's what is desired)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following

```
private void item(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    TreeView tree = sender as TreeView;
    TreeViewItem item = tree.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
}
```